# A phrase meaning a drawback turned out to be an advantage

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

I remember having heard one before but can't say how it went. The phrase says that what seemed like a disadvantage - became an advantage.
If anyone knows anything even similar to this definition - it'd much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The expression **silver lining** comes pretty close:   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/silver-lining

Comment: The phrase [***It's not a bug, it's a feature***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22not+a+bug%22+%22a+feature%22) has become increasingly common in this context.

Comment: Another apt phrase is *blessing in disguise*.

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's a feature" is usually used as a joke, though - with the meaning that it is a disadvantage, but if you asked the person responsible they'd call it an advantage to get out of having to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**Snatching victory from the jaws of defeat** is a relatively common expression meaning: to take a situation that was going badly and make it have a good outcome. That deals with a specific situation (a sports game, a political race, an exam) and not so much a *trait* which could be an advantage or a disadvantage.

**Every cloud has a silver lining** is a saying that means even a bad situation can lead to some good, which is similar but not quite what you want.

To **have a hidden talent** is to have a skill that very few people know about.

**What doesn't kill you makes you stronger** is a saying meaning that anything you can power through will, eventually, build your strength and character by virtue of having experienced it.

None of these are precisely what you're looking for but I hope they help a little!

Answer (score 0):

Another one that fits perfectly is "**it was a blessing in disguise**".